# IE9 createTreeWalker - no such interface supported

Tags: javascript, dom

My treewalker is simply intended to prevent AJAX loaded content from being loaded if any elements have an ID that is already in my XHTML application.

IE9 keeps giving me "no such interface supported". I know one of the parameters is a reference to a function. I don't need anything fancy, I simply want to iterate over all elements unconditionally. What do I need to change? The "xml" is a valid element object.

First attempt...

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(xml,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);
```

Second attempt...

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(xml,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,function() {return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker) show this as an example (modified to fit your case):

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    xml,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    { acceptNode: function(node) { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; } },
    false
);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message and I made sure that I cleared the cache before trying.